# Julia automatically deleting registry/general

Tags: package, julia, registry, environment, pluto.jl

Every time I execute the code below inside my main.jl file using a Pluto notebook my registry/general folder is deleted automatically and all the packages are automatically reinstalled. After that, the resto of the notebook works perfectly fine but this is a little annoying since it takes 10 mins every time I restart the notebook kernel

```
[1] begin
    using Pkg
    Pkg.activate(tempname())
end


[2] Pkg.add(["Images",
         "Colors",
         "ImageMagick",
         "PlutoUI",
         "Hyperscript",
         "ImageFiltering"])
[3] begin
    using Images
    using ImageMagick
    using Statistics
    using LinearAlgebra
    using ImageFiltering
end
```

This appears to happen even though the required packages are already installed and work. I have made sure that the regualar project.toml and manifest.toml files are in the folder of the main.jl doc. Any idea what specifically I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not generate a new Project directory with every run of your code.

Instead of that try `Pkg.activate(".")`. Dot (`.`) stands for the current folder,  or just provide the folder where your main.jl  is located.

Comment: thanks. Worked well on the file in question but I still witnessed weird things going on with packages on other Pluto notebooks. I figure it was due to Windows since I switched to unix and now it all works like charm